# How to use a FOR loop to split a sentence onto new lines Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, slice

I know how to use a split() however, I'm having a bit of memory loss here. I want to use a FOR loop which will split up a user inputted sentence whenever a space occurs. Each word should thus be displayed on a seperate line when I run the program. Every time I run this, I'm just putting every letter onto a new line, but I want every word on a new line. My code so far:

```
string = "My name is Graham"
length = len(string)
for index in range(length):
    if string[index] == " ":
        print(" ")
    else:
        print(string[index])
```

Comment: You're not currently using split anywhere. Also note that Python for loop is a for each: you could replace your current code with `for char in string: print(char)`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm purposedly not using split as I want to print this on a new line on the shell. I know how to use split.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're not just using it, then: `for word in string.split(): print(word)`. And why do you special case spaces?

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thanks! Had a brain freeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this ...

```
listSplitted = [x for x in string.split(' ')]
for x in listSplitted:
    print(x)
```

you could also try to implement the split method yourself (which is closer to what you gave as example):

```
lastIdx=0
for idx in range(length):
    if string[idx] == ' ':
        print(string[lastIdx:idx-1])
        lastIdx = idx+1
```

but you could also adapt the `print` method to do what you want:

```
for idx in range(length):
    if string[idx] == ' ':
        print("") # this appends a new line
    else:
        print(string[idx], end='')
```

for the last case, please refer also to https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print

( I have not tested the code in python, so there might be +-1 index offset, you'll easily find)

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension and `.join()` to do this in one line:

```
print('\n'.join([x for x in string.split()]))
```

and if you wanna keep the spacing and print them too, you can use:

```
print('\n \n'.join([x for x in string.split()]))
```

You can also use a `for-loop` as the following:

```
for word in string.split():
    print(word)
    print(' ')
```

remove 2nd print if you don't want spaces.

Comment: I like the last solution but it can be even shorter without second print. Instead you can just type: print(word, end = '  ')

Comment: @Nenad But it was mentioned that each word should be printed in a new line including the space =)

Comment: I see. Then you can write something like this: for word in string.split():
 print(' ' + word, end = '\n')